# Windows 8.1 failing to install updates and unable to install Windows 10 (not sure if related)

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10, windows-update, updates

My computer is currently running Windows 8.1 Pro with Media Center, and for several months has been **failing to install a number of important Windows updates**, shown in the screenshot below. After installing the updates, I restart the computer as required, then **a message reading something like "Failed to configure updates, reverting changes" is displayed**. The same cycle occurs when I attempt to install the updates again or when they're installed automatically.

I've tried installing them individually as well as just selecting updates that haven't failed previously but Windows seems to try installing all of them regardless and reverting changes as before (e.g. I select 1 update, then a message saying "Installing update 1 of 23" is displayed on restart despite only selecting 1 update). This means I'm unable to find exactly which update is causing the problem.

Also, recently I reserved a copy of Windows 10 for my computer. However, the app said Windows 10 is downloading in the background for several days of using my computer and Task Manager showed virtually no network usage from the app, and clicking the "View download progress" button closed the app. **Could this be because the app is waiting for all Windows updates to be installed before it actually downloads Windows 10?** Even worse, **the Get Windows 10 notification seems to have now completely disappeared**.

So my question is: **Does anyone have any ideas for fixing these issues of Windows updates failing to install and Windows 10 not downloading**, and **are they related**?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to Windows 10 via official tool: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: Oh okay, would I use my current Windows 8 product key for that?

Comment: Actually just saw on that webpage that I shouldn't need a product key